# LitElement get updated attribute value when property set to new value

Tags: javascript, web-component, custom-element, lit-element, lit-html

I want attribute should update when property was set to new value.
so what I did is to call the `element.requestUpdate()` so that I can get the updated attribute, but requestUpdate is async.
Is there other way to get the updated attribute without calling requestUpdate? 
Stackblitz URL 
=> https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-nojnqa

[LitElement get updated attribute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t73KE.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Properties and attributes

Actually you don't need to manually update attributes when properties change: lit-element has a built-in functionality to reflect property changes to attributes.

From the [documentation](https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/guide/properties#reflected-attributes):

> You can configure a property so that whenever it changes, its value is reflected to its observed attribute. For example:
>
> ```
> // Value of property "myProp" will reflect to attribute "myprop"
> myProp: { reflect: true }
> ```

In your example you're already using `reflect: true` but you're declaring the properties with the JS notation in a TS environment.

This:

```
static get properties() {
  return {
    name: {
      type: String,
      reflect: true
    }
  }
}
```

should be this:

```
@property({
  reflect: true,
})
name: string;
```

### Timing

Then there is a little timing problem. This code that you put in `index.html`:

```
<script>
  (async function() {
    const element = document.querySelector('#app').querySelector('hello-name')
    element.name = 'Maria'
    await element.requestUpdate()

    console.log(element.getAttribute('name')) //// result => Maria
  })()
</script>
```

is run *after* the custom element is appended to the dom, but *before* LitElement's property logic initialization. If you try to defer the execution of this code you'll find that LitElement's property-attribute reflection will work as expected.

### Waiting for the update

Calling `element.requestUpdate()` is not necessary because the setter `element.name = ...` already calls `requestUpdate()` under the hood.

For this kind of scenario LitElement has a getter, [`updateComplete`](https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/api/classes/_lit_element_.litelement.html#updatecomplete) that returns a promise that resolves when the update cycle has completed.

```
element.name = 'Maria';
await element.updateComplete;
console.log(element.getAttribute('name')); // Maria
```

Lastly, if your concern is about the use of `async`/`await` there is a number of alternatives:

- replacing `async`/`await` with `Promise#then()/catch()`,
- using `setImmediate()`/`setTimeout()` to wait for the update microtask to end,
- firing an `Event` when the attribute has changed.

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-kcfjny) is a fork of your StackBlitz with a possible solution.

Comment: thanks for this it helps firstUpdate is the key :) then i create a dispatcher